# how to manually install the pre-build python package into conda environment

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, conda

Need to install Azure cosmos-db python sdk via conda. But I can only install up to version 3.1.2 and 4.2.0 is needed in the project. I wonder how can I manually load the prebuild cosmo sdk in to the conda environment?

I have a env.yml file shown as follow, the enviroment is created via `conda env create -f <path_to_env.yml>`

```
name: cco_1410
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:  
  - azure-cosmos=4.2.0 (this would lead to fail)
  - python=3
  - fastapi=0.65.0
  - pytest
```

install 4.2.0 version via conda is not possible. Conda is only able to install up to 3.1.2 version

```
 conda search azure-cosmos
```

returns

```
/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.2) or chardet (4.0.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
azure-cosmos                   3.0.2            py_0  conda-forge
azure-cosmos                   3.1.0            py_0  conda-forge
azure-cosmos                   3.1.1            py_0  conda-forge
azure-cosmos                   3.1.2            py_0  conda-forge
azure-cosmos                   3.1.2            py_0  pkgs/main
```

Comment: [Looking at the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/azure-cosmos-feedstock/pulls), the auto-builds failed for those versions and no one has been working on them. If you're feeling voluntaristic, it would be nice if someone motivated would take up the mantle on that feedstock. Then you'd have a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of someone [fixing the Conda Forge feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/azure-cosmos-feedstock/pulls) so that the newer versions are available on Conda, it is a PyPI package, so one can also install it through Pip:

```yaml
name: cco_1410
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:  
  - python=3
  - fastapi=0.65.0
  - pytest
  - pip
  - pip:
    - azure-cosmos==4.2.0
```

Please read [the Conda documentation on installing non-Conda packages](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft releases Azure SDK packages for conda every three months in Microsoft channel (https://anaconda.org/microsoft).

azure-cosmos 4.2.0 was included in Sep. release.

You can find it from https://anaconda.org/microsoft/azure-cosmos.

(I work in MS in the SDK team)